# line of Java is printing duplicates

Tags: java

```
case 2:
    System.out.println("Please enter Book ID: ");
    String userinput2 = sc.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < myBooks.size(); i++) {
        if (myBooks.get(i).getBookID().contains(userinput2)) {
            System.out.println("BookID: " + myBooks.get(i).getBookID() + "\nTitle: "
                    + myBooks.get(i).getTitle() + "\nAuthor: " + myBooks.get(i).getAuthor());
            System.out.println("Please enter new details of book");
            System.out.println("Title: ");
            String userinput7 = sc.next();
            myBooks.get(i).setTitle(userinput7);
            System.out.println("Author: ");
            String u1 = sc.next();
            myBooks.get(i).setAuthor(u1);
            myBooks.get(i).setOnLoan(false);
            myBooks.get(i).setNumLoans(0);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("The book has been successfully updated");
            System.out.println("Book ID: " + myBooks.get(i).getBookID() + " " + "\nTitle: "
                    + myBooks.get(i).getTitle() + " " + "\nAuthor: " + myBooks.get(i).getAuthor());
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        }
        else { System.out.println("Please enter a correct bookID");
        }
    }
```

I'm having a problem with my validation check. If the user enters a bookID that doesn't exist, instead of printing out "please enter a correct bookID" once, it prints it out 4 times, which amounts to the number of objects i have in the array list. Is there a way to sort this?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses.

Comment: You should be checking for duplicates first, before you add any new items

Comment: And you are also not allowing user to input again after the else executes, hence it keeps executing till loop finishes. Try adding `userinput2 = sc.next();` in `else` block perhaps.

Comment: or add a `break;` in the `else` block

Comment: Sorry I've just started learning how to program. That seems to have worked thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your else statement is in the middle of the for statement

```
for (int i = 0; i < myBooks.size(); i++) {
        if (myBooks.get(i).getBookID().contains(userinput2)) {
            [[do stuff]]
        }
        else { System.out.println("Please enter a correct bookID");
        }
}
```

It looks like it should be in the middle of the if statement

```
if (myBooks.get(i).getBookID().contains(userinput2)) {
    for (int i=...) {
       [[do stuff]]
    }
}
else { System.out.println("Please enter a correct bookID");
}
```